# Vue CLI: Unable to load localhost:8080

Tags: webpack, server, localhost, vue-cli

I currently have a Webpack server configured with Vue CLI 4.5.11. I have been using this server for months, and I don't know what has changed, but `localhost:8080` has suddenly become inaccessible on all my browsers (Chrome, Safari, Postman) except for Firefox which seems to be the only one working for some reason. On Chrome, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

That being said, using `127.0.0.1:8080` will work fine, as well as changing the port (ex. `localhost:8081`)

Here is briefly how my `vue.config.js` file looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/assets/app',
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost'
    port: 8080,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  }
}
```

I have also checked to make sure nothing was running on port `8080`. Finally, I even reset my Mac!

The only "hack" that I found was to start my server like this: `yarn serve --host 0.0.0.0 --host localhost --port` (yes, the two `host` option are necessary for it to work...)

That being said, I would rather find the actual problem... Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

P.S. I am on Mac OS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

try to modify host to your Local address
like:
host:'127.0.0.1'

Comment: Seems to be working but I still don't get why `localhost:8080` won't work...

Comment: try to change modify package.json like this                                                        
    "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  },